# How do I compute $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to 0} \tfrac{e^x+\sin x -1}{\ln(1+x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm a Calculus I teacher's assistant. One of my students asked me how to compute this limit

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^x+\sin x -1}{\ln(1+x)}$$

I could not solve it. I need some hint.

P.s: I'm not supposed to solve this using differentiation. My classes haven't entered that yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like a comment along with that downvote, thank you.

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule maybe ?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Members use to downvote when you seem to expect them to do all the work for you.

Comment: If differentiation is not allowed (and presumably neither Taylor development), what can you use as defintions for $\exp$, $\sin$ and $\ln$ ?

Comment: Have the students seen power series?  I'm guessing probably not.  If this is an exercise in a textbook, perhaps it is only included to show that techniques seen so far can't do everything.  I wouldn't assign such an exercise at that point in the course, but maybe I'll change my mind about that some day.  If a student was asking you about an exercise that was not assigned, I see nothing wrong with telling the student that the problem requires techniques not yet covered at that point in the course.

Comment: Exponential and logarithms were defined loosely and in an intuitive approach. The more precise definition of those functions are not even taught to engineering students at all (with terms lime 'exponential at basis $a$' and so on).

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I don't think this is one of those cases where the poster shows insufficient effort.  I think the only good reason for expecting some account of the poster's efforts is to filter out cases in which the poster is merely copying an assigned question without even understanding the question.

Comment: @Michael: don't tell me, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I was responding to your comment.

Answer (score 11):

Note that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x+\sin x - 1}{\ln(1+x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{e^x-1}{x} + \dfrac{\sin x}{x}}{\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}} = \dfrac{\left[\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}\right] + \left[\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right]}{\left[\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right]}$.

Can you evaluate those 3 limits using only stuff that the students have seen? This will depend on how your book defines the functions $\sin x$, $e^x$, and $\ln x$. In most books $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ is shown geometrically (without the need for derivatives). I'm not sure how your book defines $e^x$ and $\ln x$.

Comment: Yes, this is the perfect solution. It's a nice use for some notable limits, thanks!

Comment: Assuming that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}$$ is known to be $1$, $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$$ can be derived by inversion, or conversely. I dare not mention $x\to ix$.

Comment: Exponential and logarithms were defined loosely and in an intuitive approach. The more precise definition of those functions are not even taught to engineering students at all (with terms lime 'exponential at basis $a$' and so on).

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor series:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x+\sin x -1}{\log(1+x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)+x-1+o(x)}{x+o(x)}=2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use l'hospital's rule:

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^x+\sin x -1}{\ln(1+x)}$$
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^x+\cos x}{\frac{1}{1+x}}$$
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0} (e^x + \cos x)(x+1) = (1+1)*(1) = 2$$

Comment if you have questions.

Comment: It works. I forgot to mention that I should try to solve it with just limit techniques. Going to edit my question.